# What are the vertical asymptotes for this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$F(x)=\frac{5x^2}{4x^2}+9 $

Okay so when i graphed this function there are no vertical asymptotes but why is that ? 
Becuase if u set the denominator equal to zero then u can solve and get the vertical asymptotes

Comment: If what you plotted is $ \ \frac{5x^2}{4x^2 + 9} \ $ , then the denominator is always positive for real numbers, so you would have no vertical asymptotes.  Is that the function you intended to work with?  What is it you have been calculating?

Comment: Yea i tried to set denominator equal to zero but when x=0 then so does the numerator so thats not a vertical asymptote

Comment: So what you are calculating is $ \ \frac{5x^2}{4x^2} \ + \ 9 \ $ .  While this is undefined at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ , it is equal to  $ \ \frac{5 }{4 } \ + \ 9 \ $ for all other values of $ \ x \ $ , so the function does not "run off to infinity" anywhere.  The graph will simply have a "hole" at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ (which doesn't show up on most graphing utilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: since $$\frac{5x^2}{4x^2+9}=5/4-{\frac {45}{16\,{x}^{2}+36}}$$ no vertical asyptote exists.